# DNS Server VS DNS Record

Tags: domain-name-system, localhost

This question is to clarify a fundamental concept so that I can properly understand an error message.  My server threw a warning message that implored me to:

> add 127.0.0.1 to the list of DNS servers

Would that mean that they are asking me to create a new DNS record or are they talking about something else?

If it's the former, I already have an A record for the localhost:

```
localhost.domain.co.    IN  A   127.0.0.1
```

So, might it need something else?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What was the warning message?

Comment: Which O.S. are you using?

Comment: @TeroKilkanen Thanks for the response! It was a warning message from virtualmin that stated `Virtualmin is configured to setup DNS zones, but this system is not setup to use itself as a DNS server. Either add 127.0.0.1 to the list of DNS servers, or turn off the BIND feature on the module config page.`  I obfuscated it because I wanted to clarify the likely word usage, rather than getting a whole bunch of answers to the error itself.

Comment: @Massimo Thanks for the response.  I'm using Ubuntu 12.04.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's asking you to add localhost (127.0.0.1) as a DNS server (not a record).
So in other words, the OS will use 127.0.0.1 as a DNS server.

I don't really know what OS you're running so I can't help you further on how to fix that.

Comment: Thanks so much for the clarification.  May have been simple but that's exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

On Windows systems, this can happen if the server is running the DNS service and the user leaves the DNS server fields empty in a network adapter configuration; the message basically means "you have not configured this NIC to use any DNS server, this system *is* a DNS server, thus you'd probably want to use it".

Depending on your network configuration, the message can be safely ignored, unless you actually want the system to use its own DNS services for name resolution.

Case in point: one time I had to manage a server which was acting both as a perimeter firewall (using ForeFront TMG) for the company network and as the main DNS server for the company's public DNS domain. The server had two NICs, and it was a domain member; its internal NIC was configured to use two AD domain controllers as DNS servers, while the external NIC didn't have any DNS Server configured, because it only needed a public IP address. The configuration was perfectly legit, but the OS kept pestering me to configure 127.0.0.1 as the DNS server for the external NIC, because it saw there was no DNS server configured there, and the computer was running the DNS service. Needless to say, this would have been completely *wrong*, but there was no way to have Windows just shut up about it.